# how to get a page from a xps file?

Tags: c#, xps, xps-generation

I'm writting an application in c# that take a Xps Document and create another xps documet that contains only one selected page from the original document, I was searching for an API that work with XPS files but I don't find anyone that do this work.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You should look into Document Toolkit.  Although it's not exactly what you're looking for there is a lot of code that he uses to parse XPS files.  Essentially they are just Zip files with an index.

Comment: You are aware of the classes in the .NET System.Windows.Xps namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking in [System.Windows.Xps.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.aspx)? That seems to contain everything you'll need to pull apart an XPS document and generate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try looking into [GhostXPS](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gxpsdnld.html).  It isn't an API per se, but you could call the application via System.Process to convert.  Documentation is a bit light but you can probably use the help switch (-?) on the application to figure it out.  Glancing at that help output, it does seem to support page operations.